# Python pyowm library average tempature

Tags: python, string, char, openweathermap

I have the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import pyowm

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.weatherlabel = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        owm = pyowm.OWM()
        owm = pyowm.OWM('*censored*')
        observation = owm.weather_at_place('Modiin,il')
        test = owm.weather_at_place('Modiin,il').get_weather().get_temperature('celsius')
        print(test)
        self.label.configure(text=now,font=("Helvetica",40),fg="white",bg="black")
        self.weatherlabel.configure(text= test,font=("Helvetica",40),fg="white",bg="black")
        self.root.configure(background='black')
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)
        self.label.place(x=1310,y=10)
        self.weatherlabel.place(x=400,y=400)

app = App()
```

Is there a way to request average temp, max temp and min temp separately instead of the huge string it gives? The output here is `{'temp': 30.48, 'temp_max': 31.0, 'temp_min': 30.0, 'temp_kf': None}`.

I know there's the addressing each char in the string way with test[x] but this isn't reliable unless I add a lot of parameters to detect if it's a single digit number or a double digit number in each segment. I want a more simple solution.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a dictionary, have you tried to show the results like this?

```
dict = {'temp': 30.48, 'temp_max': 31.0, 'temp_min': 30.0, 'temp_kf': None}

print dict['temp']
print "Maximum temperature : {}".format(dict['temp_max'])
```

Output:

```
30.48
Maximum temperature : 31.0
```

If the results are in the `test` variable, you can do something like this:

```
def update_clock(self):
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    owm = pyowm.OWM()
    owm = pyowm.OWM('*censored*')
    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Modiin,il')
    test = owm.weather_at_place('Modiin,il').get_weather().get_temperature('celsius')
    print "Average temperature : {}".format(test['temp'])
    print "Minimum temperature : {}".format(test['temp_min'])
    print "Maximum temperature : {}".format(test['temp_max'])
    self.label.configure(text=now,font=("Helvetica",40),fg="white",bg="black")
    self.weatherlabel.configure(text= test,font=("Helvetica",40),fg="white",bg="black")
    self.root.configure(background='black')
    self.root.after(1000, self.update_clock)
    self.label.place(x=1310,y=10)
    self.weatherlabel.place(x=400,y=400)
```

Comment: That's not a tuple, it's a dictionary.